# Laptop doesn't work after closing

Tags: 18.04, lock-screen

I have Xiaomi Notebook Pro (CPU: Intel Core i7-8550U, GPU: GPU: GeForce MX150) with Ubuntu 18.04. After "sleep mode" with open laptop it works fine. But after closing the laptop I see the next screen.

[image]

Comment: clearly an issue from `nvidia-driver`; try an update of it